# Define black region in HSV color space

Tags: opencv, colors, filter, hsv

I want to find boundaries of black region

http://i40.tinypic.com/2lbi9s9.jpg
http://i44.tinypic.com/ka4vuc.jpg

I tried different values for black, but coluld find average value so region is thresholded in both pictures
One of ranges is

```
inRange(src_HSV, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(180, 150, 50), src_HSV);
```

Another is

```
inRange(src_HSV, Scalar(100, 40, 140), Scalar(140, 160, 255), src_HSV);
```

I tried to search the Internet for values of black, but couldn't find anything suitable for this case, having different tones of black

Comment: You might try to open the images with gimp to pick some pixel samples.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger thanks, I tried color picker tools, but they give really different range, not to be used for thresholding

Answer (score 3):

Note that in HSV, black is defined as V=0, independently of H and S (in your case, you probably need to look for small values of V and S). I would ignore the H component.

Answer (score 1):

```
inRange(src_HSV, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(179,50, 100), src_HSV);
```

for black and grey shades.
Anyways it is application specific.
Follow [this link](http://cell0907.blogspot.in/2013/07/rgb-and-hsv.html) to get good insights on HSV:

Answer (score 0):

Would this be an option (in RGB):

if ((red + green + blue) <= 64) {

// black
} else {

// not black
}

If not you could try HSL (hue, saturation, lightness) values and set black if lightness < 10% ...

Comment: thanks, HSL helped, but not 10, 100 is enough i think

`cvtColor(src, src_HSV, CV_BGR2HLS);`

`inRange(src_HSV, Scalar(0, 0, 0), Scalar(180, 100, 255), src_HSV);`